# Update top rows in Access table that match condition

Tags: ms-access

I don't have an autonumbered primary key in a Microsoft Access table.
I am interested to know if there is any equivalent syntax to this query that is possible in Sql Server:

```
update top(2) [dbtest].[dbo].[myTable]
set ColA = ColA+13
where ColA = 5
```

This code updates only the first 2 rows (depending on what you specify in the paratheses after TOP) that match the condition specified in the "where" clause.

However I am in need of the Access variant, if it's even possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a primary key on the table, this should work:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET ColA = ColA + 13
WHERE PKField IN(SELECT TOP 2 PKField FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = 5)
```

*NOTE: You may want to consider an Order By clause somewhere in order to make sure you're updating the relevant 2 records.*